# How to update data in Grid View using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try to update data in grid view using command line but I get the error like:

> Procedure or function 'UpdateState' expects parameter '@StateName', which was not supplied.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateState
    @StateName varchar(30)
AS
    update tblState 
    set StateName = @StateName
```

`Aspx` page:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
       GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
       FillStates();
 }

 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
       int Sid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
       TextBox StateName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
       p.Sid = Sid;
       p.StateName = StateName.Text;
       p.UpdateState(p);
       GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
       FillStates();
}
```

Source:

```
public void UpdateState(Property p)
{
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateState", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", p.Sid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateName", p.StateName);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: your command should specify its type: 
**cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure**... also please send the correct number of parameters to thae stored procedure

Comment: You need a WHERE clause in that stored procedure unless you want to update the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

add command type

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateState", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", p.Sid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateName", p.StateName);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```